# ssh & sftp work with netns, but sshfs doesn’t

Tags: ssh, vpn, sftp

Here, I use `netns` to use a VPN, but `sshfs` doesn’t work properly. Here's what I tried:

```
root@ubuntu:/mnt# ip netns exec secured sshfs -d -o sshfs_debug -p PORT USER@HOST: MOUNTPOINT
SSHFS version 2.8
FUSE library version: 2.9.7
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-oPort=PORT> <-2> <USER@HOST> <-s> <sftp>
Server version: 3
Extension: posix-rename@openssh.com <1>
Extension: statvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: fstatvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: hardlink@openssh.com <1>
Extension: fsync@openssh.com <1>
unique: 1, opcode: INIT (26), nodeid: 0, insize: 56, pid: 0
INIT: 7.26
flags=0x001ffffb
max_readahead=0x00020000
   INIT: 7.19
   flags=0x00000011
   max_readahead=0x00020000
   max_write=0x00020000
   max_background=0
   congestion_threshold=0
   unique: 1, success, outsize: 40
```

That is, `ls` on the mount point lists nothing, i.e., **no entry at all**. `sshfs` **prints nothing** upon `ls`, so that also looks odd. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you yet, but this is *something* to do with `ip netns exec` isolating the mount point.  If you `ip netns exec secured bash` it will open a command prompt in that network namespace.  From there you *can* `sshfs` and use the network share.  But if you exit from that command prompt you will lose access to the mount.

Comment: @PhilipCouling You were right. I can access the mount point from the initial shell alone. Maybe, forwarding SSH traffic bound for this host to that network namespace so that it's default-routed via a VPN installed there is the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned is [Philip’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519488/28310), this is expected behavior since `ip netns exec` executes in a separate mount namespace. The trick is only to run `ssh` (which does the network communication) via `ip netns exec`, rather than the whole `sshfs` command.

That is, instead of doing this:

```
ip netns exec secured sshfs -p PORT USER@HOST: MOUNTPOINT
```

Do this:

```
sshfs -o ssh_command="ip netns exec secured ssh" -p PORT USER@HOST: MOUNTPOINT
```

Comment: Looks like a more elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is, unfortunately, expected behaviour.

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html
>
> ip netns exec automates handling of this configuration, file
>          convention for network namespace unaware applications, by creating a
>          mount namespace and bind mounting all of the per network namespace
>          configure files into their traditional location in /etc.

This means that when you use `ip netns exec <namespace> <command>`, the command will not only execute in a different network namespace but also a different mount namespace.  So `sshfs` is successfully mounting as you request, but you can't see that mount.

---

## Workaround 1

You could just open a command prompt into the network and work from there:

```
ip netns exec secured bash
sshfs -d -o sshfs_debug -p PORT USER@HOST: MOUNTPOINT
# ... use MOUNTPOINT
```

## Workaround 2

After creating the share you can re-enter that mount namespace:

```
    ip netns exec secured sshfs -d -o sshfs_debug -p PORT USER@HOST: MOUNTPOINT
    ps -ef | grep sshfs
    root 1880     1  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshfs -p PORT USER@HOST:. MOUNTPOINT

    # Now run a command (ls) in the same mount namespace
    nsenter --mount -t 1880 ls

    # You can of course run a command prompt there
    nsenter --mount -t 1880 bash
```

## Workaround 3

*Note this is likely to be more complex and I've not explored this option properly.*

As per the quote above, the mount namespace is used for extra network configuration.   But theoretically it's not required as you can achieve the same effect using a `chroot`.

You could experiment with entering the network namespace using `nsenter --net` and using a `chroot` to setup the require network config.  This would then allow you to execute `sshfs` inside your main mount namespace.

Comment: Reverting back to the main mount space, i.e, `ip netns exec secured nsenter --mount --target 1 sshfs ...` works. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I've came across this question and poked around.

Indeed `ip netns` it seems creates a *temporary MOUNT* namespace and executes whatever mount (`nfs`, `sshfs`, etc) in that namespace and as soon the command is finished that MOUNT namespace is gone and so is the mount point.

Thus the universal solution would be to execute mount command in NET namespace only with `nsenter` command.

E.g. if your mount command is: `sshfs -p PORT USER@HOST: MOUNTPOINT`
then execute:

`nsenter --net=/run/netns/ns-secured sshfs -p PORT USER@HOST: MOUNTPOINT`

and the mount point will be kept in the global (default) namespace. It also will work for other types of remote network FS (e.g. NFS).